# What is the analogue of a covering map in algebraic geometry?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, soft-question

It is well known that many of the concepts of algebraic geometry have some corresponding concept in differential manifolds. Take for example, the idea of a tangent space, or of cohomology of smooth manifolds/schemes. Specifically, many properties of morphisms in algebraic geometry have direct analogues in differential topology -- such as proper morphisms/maps, or embedding of manifolds/immersion of schemes.

So is there any type of morphism of schemes, or of varieties, that can be intuitively considered analogous to a covering map? Furthermore, is there any sort of concept of a "universal cover" of a variety, some cover that is particularly well behaved (simply connected, in the case of smooth manifolds)?

Comment: The notion of a local covering corresponds to an [etale morphism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%89tale_morphism).  Variants of this give covering maps, and taking the collection of all coverings you can define the etale fundamental group of a scheme.

Comment: (1) I don't know about intuitive, since it's not immediately clear why one has to drop the notion of local isomorphism. The first example is always to take the squaring map $x \mapsto x^2$ and delete $0$. This looks like a degree two cover but of course Zariski opens are way too big to make this true in the old sense. (2) It's very instructive to try to define the topological fundamental group in this way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equivalent of covering in algebraic geometry is the notion etale cover. There is not a notion of universal cover, but the etale cover of $X$ define the etale fundamental is a projective limit of finite groups.

Comment: The problem with the universal cover is that it is usually a transcendent construction, like the minimal example of the complement of zero in the affine line shows.

Comment: I don't understand your remark. The question was is there a notion of universal cover in algebraic geometry. The answer is no unless  (perhaps if) you consider formal schemes

Comment: Etale cover have finite fibres

Comment: Tsemo, an etale cover may not have finite covers. You mean finite etale cover. As Mariano points out, infinite covers are usually non-algebraic as $\exp:\mathbb{C}\to\mathbb{C}^\times$ shows. Also, there is a 'pro-universal cover'. This has been developed, for example, by Vakil et al.

Answer (score 2):

> is there any sort of concept of a "universal cover" of a variety, some cover that is particularly well behaved

In addition to the coverings associated with the SGA fundamental groups  there is the Vakil-Wickelgren universal cover, http://arxiv.org/abs/0902.3464 and the recent work of Scholze and Bhatt on the pro-etale topology.